# Magento 1.9 set exisiting address as default billing and shipping address

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer-address, customer-session

I'm writing some magenta 1.9 codes for set existing customer address to set as default billing and shipping address

```
<?php $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId->getId()); 
$data = array();

foreach ($customer->getAddresses() as $address){

$data = $address->toArray();
  if(trim($data['postcode']) !=''){
  $address->setIsDefaultBilling('1');
  $address->setIsDefaultShipping('1');
  $address->save();
break;
}
}
?>
```

But it doesn't seems works, anyone have idea to fix this please, Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
if(trim($data['postcode']) !='')
{
    $customerAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
    $customerAddress->load(trim($data['id']); //ID means address Id
    $customerAddress->setIsDefaultBilling('1');
    $customerAddress->setIsDefaultShipping('1');
    $customerAddress->save();
}
```